# How do I link gtk library more easily with cmake in windows?

Tags: windows, gtk, cmake, gtk2

I'm now doing it in a very ugly way by manually including all the required path(the gtk bundle is at `D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32`):

```
include_directories(D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/include/gtk-2.0 D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/include/glib-2.0 D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/lib/glib-2.0/include D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/include/cairo D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/include/pango-1.0 D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/lib/gtk-2.0/include D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/include/atk-1.0)
link_directories(D:/Tools/gtk+-bundle_2.20.0-20100406_win32/lib)

target_link_libraries(MyProgram gtk-win32-2.0.lib)
```

Answer (score 20):

**2019-10-29 EDIT: While this answer could still work, please note that CMake has evolved a lot since my original answer in 2011. Do some search on "modern CMake" as there have been many syntactic and best practices changes.**

**Original Answer:**

Just add the directory that contains pkg-config (which is in your gtk-bundle/bin directory) to your PATH. That way, CMake will find it.

Here's a CMakeLists.txt for a sample application written in GTK2:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4)
project (gtk-test)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules (GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)

include_directories (${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable (gtk-test main.c)
add_definitions (${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_link_libraries (gtk-test ${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
```

And the main.c file for my test app:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Hello world !");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

I tested it on Win XP with CMake 2.4 and CMake 2.8 and MinGW, and it works. It should also work outside MinGW.

Comment: OMG! The best answer. I used this advice for linking glib-2.0 library into CLion on the Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

My CMake knowledge is somewhat dated, and I try to distance myself from Windows because I find it unpleasant, but this is what `FindGTK.cmake` should be for.

According to [this post](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2005-March/006240.html) on the CMake mailing list you should:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(GTK)

IF(GTK_FOUND)
   INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK_INCLUDE_DIR})
   ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_gtk_exe my_gtk_exe.cxx)
   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_gtk_exe ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF(GTK_FOUND)
```

**Update**: It might be that the `FindGTK.cmake` is indeed too old and refers to GTK1, you might want to try `FindGTK2.cmake` instead. If it isn't part of your CMake version you can try and get it from [here](http://cmake-modules.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Modules/GTK2/FindGTK2.cmake).

**Update2**: Indeed the the FindGTK2 link above is no good for you. All it's logic is enclosed with:

```
if(UNIX)
  ...
endif(UNIX)
```

**Update3**: Again a [quote](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-May/021979.html) from the mailing list:

> ...
>   One prime example of such spread to windows is libGTK+ and friends (as one
>   other has mentioned in this thread). Some of the PLplot drivers depend on
>   parts of the GTK+ stack of libraries.  I quote from one of our developers
>   (Werner Smekal) who recently reported to the PLplot devel list about how
>   simple it is to get those drivers to work on windows:
>
> > Cairo driver in Windows or using gtk+ for plplot on Windows
> >
> > 1) Download the all-in-one bundle of the GTK+ stack including 3rd-party dependencies for windows:
> >     http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.12/gtk+-bundle-2.12.9.zip
> >     available from http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html.
> >
> > 2) Expand the package to a directory, e.g. C:\Development\gtk
> >
> > 3) Set environment variables so that CMake can find pkf-config

```
    set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\Development\gtk\lib\pkgconfig
    set PATH=C:\Development\gtk\bin;%PATH%
```

> > 4) CMake will find pkg-config and all the libraries necessary to build the
> >     pdfcairo, pscairo, pngcairo and svgcairo devices. xcairo will not be built
> >     since the X-Headers are not present.

So it seem you are missing the:

```
set PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\path\to\gtk\lib\pkgconfig
set PATH=C:\path\to\gtk\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I tried that before using the ugly one, it can't find gtk in windows.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is to look at your FindGTK2.cmake, and see how is it try to find your GTK. Also compare your copy to the copy I linked to. If you find an error in the file, consider filing a bug about it. In my experience, the CMake people are approachable and helpful.

Comment: I glanced through that file, it's only written for *nix environment.

Comment: Tried setting the environment variables, and still it's not working.. Which seems certain since the FindGTK2 is written only for *nix platform.

Comment: PkgConfig.cmake is the portable way to use any version of gtk, of course installed and registered in PATH correctly.