# How do I output installation status using gtk in c?

Tags: windows, gtk

```
int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

The above is just a empty winform,I want to output dynamic information in it(not editable),

how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GtkTextView` which you can set to be not editable. I suggest you look at this excellent [GTK tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/) which explains what widgets are available in GTK and how to put them together, accompanied by lots of example code.

Comment: @ptomato, can you also take a look at my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about CMake.