# i had developed a tool using gtk in linux. its working fine now i want to make it port to windows?

Tags: gtk, glade, gtk2

For that tool i used glade -3 to build windows  in linux and imported inside code using gtk builder, now want to port this tool to windows xp what is best way ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which version of GTK are you using?

Comment: i used gtk version 2 in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the GTK-all-in-one bundle available on [gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php). Installation procedure ins included in the README file contained in the bundle. Then, install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) on your Windows platform, and use mingw-get (the package management tool), to install msys (a shell). For a 64-bits build, you may use [MinGW-64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (which is a fork of MinGW). You then will have a platform for developing on Windows.

I personally used that platform with CMake to successfully build some code sample. Read my answer on [How do I link gtk library more easily with cmake in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows) for a CMake + GTK code sample.

Comment: is mingw create an environment like linux ?

Comment: MinGW integrates GCC in Windows. From there, you can build native Windows applications. MSYS gives you an rxvt terminal emulator, which gives you a bash shell, tab completion and all you'd expect on a shell. Once you're working in that shell, it's not really different from working on a shell on Linux, except for the file paths. The goal is to add no mingw-specific dependencies on produced binaries. That's what make it different from things like [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw#Comparison_with_Cygwin).