# How to use pkg-config in CMake (juCi++)

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk, pkg-config

I've been happily programming in C++ and compiling with g++ for quite a while. Not long ago, I'd decided to get an IDE, and I came accross [juCi++](https://github.com/cppit/jucipp).

This IDE is absolutely brilliant, but it uses CMake (or Meson) to build projects. This wasn't a problem, until I had to include a library (GTK+ 3.0 if you're wondering) using `pkg-config`. This could be done quite easily when compiling with g++, but, as I am completely new to CMake, I have no idea how to do it in the new IDE.

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Get the [documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/).

Comment: Have you tried to google? E.g., for `CMake pkg-config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your IDE handles CMake and Meson, it should be able to detect your project files. I'd say go for Meson, it's the future, and CMake syntax has a few quirks that Meson doesn't.

### Meson:

[Meson documentation](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/wiki)

He's a basic `meson.build` that expects to find your application code in `main.c` and produces a binary named `gtk3-test`.

```
project('gtk3-test', 'c')

cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
deps = dependency ('gtk+-3.0')
sources = ['main.c']

executable('gtk3-test', sources, dependencies: deps)
```

### CMake

[CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/)

For CMake, just give a look at my answer to [How do I link gtk library more easily with cmake in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows/5105523#5105523) (which also works under Linux). It was for GTK+2, but adapting it to GTK+3 is easy, so here's the `CMakeLists.txt` to use:

```
project (gtk3-test)
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules (GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

include_directories (${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable (gtk3-test main.c)
add_definitions (${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_link_libraries (gtk3-test ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Looks like I'm using CMake the old way here, here's a link more neutral about modern CMake: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6tsqcb/gtk_drops_autotools_in_favor_of_meson/dloiu1h/