# what are the differences in libnotify dev versus libnotify bin

Tags: c++, libnotify, notify-send

what is the difference in 2 libraries? Which one is prefered for production apps?
Why is there significantly different set of dependencies while installing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one [libnotify](https://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/) library. I assume you're asking about the deb packages [libnotify-bin](https://packages.debian.org/ru/bullseye/libnotify-bin) and [libnotify-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libnotify-dev).

If so, the difference is very simple: the library packages with `-dev` suffix contain [development files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#development-files) for the library, while packages with `-bin` suffix may contain some compiled binaries and utilities. To learn more about the contents of these packages, see the list of installed files for [dev](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libnotify-dev/filelist) and [bin](https://packages.debian.org/ru/bullseye/amd64/libnotify-bin/filelist) packages.

As you are using `c++` tag, I assume you need this library to send notifications from your application. In this case you should use `libnotify-dev` package which provides C API for the libnotify. `libnotify-bin` contains the `notify-send` binary which is more suitable for use in shell scripts.

Here is the minimal example using the library:

```cpp
#include <libnotify/notify.h>

int main() 
{
    notify_init("Test");
    NotifyNotification* n = notify_notification_new ("title", "text", 0);
    notify_notification_set_timeout(n, 3000);
    if (!notify_notification_show(n, 0)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Install the `libnotify-dev` package and compile the example with the following command:

```sh
g++ test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs libnotify`
```

Then run the result file to see the notification.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to know since I am trying to use it from my c++ app which runs as daemon, is there any other thing I need to take care of in this case to show notification? Also if there is cmake guide to include this package with dependencies. I was getting "glib.h header not found" error when I followed this the way desccribed in the link https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/main/Source/cmake/FindLibNotify.cmake.

Comment: @veerendragupta I think this is enough to get you started with libnotify. May be you will be interested in some additional libraries that provide a high level C++ API for the notifications, described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_notifications#C++. To be honest, I never used them and prefer to write my own wrappers around libnotify.

Comment: Error with the glib header.the h is probably due to the fact that your build system can't find glib. I think you should add GLib to the cmake project as is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730135/how-do-i-link-gtk-library-more-easily-with-cmake-in-windows/5105523#5105523.

Comment: Thanks..it doesn't send notifiation to other users.  how can I use it to run from a daemon running as root user & notify all the users.